# best way to manage team membership in drupal-based site

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

I'm creating a site to manage a sports league. At the beginning of each season, there's a draft during which captains choose their teams. Currently, I'm considering using Organic Groups and/or a user reference field on the Team type. (Which one? Both?)

I'd like to provide a clean interface for managing the draft where an admin would have a bucket of users and could drag them into buckets for each team. Or between tables or via a dropdown interface or whatever. I'm less concerned about the interface at the moment than I am that:

- the admin can see and edit all the users
- grouped by team
- with an ungrouped group
- easily move them between the groups

I imagine I might be able to use views bulk operations to whip something up, but before I do, is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good scenario for organic groups, as you suspected. You can make a private group per team, and only allow administrators or 'team captains' to add people to a given team. A views query can allow you to show a page of players who don't belong to any group. We do something similar for project teams.

Comment: I'm actually leaning the other direction. So far, the interface for adding people to a group seems to be lousy. Is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, perfect scenario for Organic Groups! That's exactly what that module was meant to do.